# API яндекс карт блокирует другие скрипты на сайте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

куда смотреть, если при подключении скрипта 
https: //yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js

для работы API карт, перестают работать несколько других скриптов? но сама карта работает корректно.

*сайт на вордпресс
**ошибок в консоли нет
***данный скрипт подключается в самом низу страницы

нижеследующее же не должно никак влиять?

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://tech.yandex.ru/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

как это поправить?

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решен асинхронной загрузкой карты

*рано радовался. всем конфликтным скриптам выставлен атрибут defer не сильно помогло, работает раз через 5.

долго ставил эксперименты, и сработала такая комбинация: все скрипты defer, а этот async...
я не знаю по какой магии это работает

Comment: Хорошо бы показать, как это делается, чтоб и другим помогло)

Comment: рано радовался. всем конфликтным скриптам выставлен атрибут defer,
не сильно помогло, работает раз через 5.